# WPF Telerik GridViewComboBoxColumn not showing data

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

So originally I was using GridViewDataColumn, it works fine. but one of the columns I want to change it to drop down style, so I switched one of them to GridViewComboBoxColumn, but the data in that column will not show anymore.

Here is my codes

```
<telerik:RadGridView Itemsource="{Binding Namelist}" margin...>

  <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding = "{Binding id}" Header = "ID"/>
    <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn DatamemberBinding = "{Binding name}" Header = "Name"/>

  </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

So that name column working fine with GridViewDataColumn, but not ComboBoxColumn.
Do I need to create a new list for itemsource?

Comment: @FelixCastor Thank you, so the display data is fine, just because I'm missing the selections, so the data is no showing?